Spresense SDK環境でStepCounterが動作しない
問題
Spresense SDK環境で、examplesのstep_counterを動作させようとしているのですが動作しません。
センサーはBMI270を使用しており、下記コンフィグおよびコードを変更しました。
■ example
/spresense/examples/step_counter/accel_sensor.cxx
-#include <nuttx/sensors/bmi160.h>
+#include <nuttx/sensors/bmi270.h>

■ sdkコンフィグ
# CONFIG_SENSORS_BMI160 is not set
CONFIG_SENSORS_BMI270=y
CONFIG_SENSORS_BMI270_I2C=y

実行すると、AccelSensorOpenでphysical_sensor_sendを送った後、応答が来ず止まってしまいます。
AEG
board_i2cdev_initialize: Initializing /dev/i2c0..
board_bmi270_initialize: Initializing BMI270..
bmi270_checkid: devid: 0024
bmi270_register: BMI270 driver loaded successfully!

NuttShell (NSH) NuttX-12.3.0


nsh> step_counter
register_client: sesor id :  1 >> 00000400
register_client: sesor id :  9 >> 00000400
register_client: sesor id : 10 >> 00100000
start sensoring...
physical_sensor_send

BMI270でStepCounterを動作させる方法をご教授お願いします。
その他
BMI270が動作しているかの確認のため,exapmlesのsixaisを動作させたところ正常にセンサ値が取れたので、
センサー自体は問題ないようです。
こちらも、コンフィグおよびコードをBMI160→BMI270に変更して確認しました。
環境
Windows 11
Spresense SDK(IDE版)での開発
SDK v3.2.0 (2024/02/09)
